# IOS7: Webview memory leak

Tags: ios7, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I know this is a very recurring topic but, i tried all the suggested solutions they seem not to work...
The scenario:

1. I load an empty view and i add at run time an UIWebview.It is a global variable,initiated only once.
2. the initial memory usage (by Xcode 5.1) is ~6MBytes.
3. i will load in the view a series of url using a button event.Each time is pressed a new page will be loaded.
4. i load in the webView the first page from internet with few image and one video.
5. After the loadRequest is completed, the memory is ~20Mbytes.
6. Every time i load a new page the memory increases.
7. The memory stays the same even when i load a new controller...

What I tried so far:

- To use the [NSURLCache sharedURLCache] and related functions to instantiate a fixed amount of cache in the Application delegate: the App does not care...memory changes despite the limit of 32MBytes i set.
- To set to nil the global variable: no effect.
- To use temporary UIWebview(s) instead of the global one; views are removed from the superview each time the controller changes: no effect.

None of this tentatives have been successful...the memory increase and it is never released.
If i start the video from the web browser and then i load a new controller, the sound of the video still runs in the background...

What am I missing???
Thank you in advance